# Add class to existing modules (external library)

Tags: javascript, typescript, phaser-framework

I'm trying to extend Phaser by adding a new `Phaser.Physics.Box2D` module. Internally Phaser already use this module but it's an additional plugin and **I want to define my own**.

I'm using TypeScript for my project. And I want to use it to extend phaser the right way. I found [this issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10859) that explain how to add a new definition (interface) but nothing about the addition of code (an implementation).

Here is what I tried (I also tried many variants).

```js
// This is part of phaser typescript definitions
// The code I try to add is at the end.
// You can test it on https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html
declare module "phaser-ce" {
    export = Phaser;
}

declare class Phaser {
    static VERSION: string;
    static DEV_VERSION: string;
    static GAMES: Phaser.Game[];
}

declare module Phaser {
    enum blendModes {

        NORMAL,
        ADD,
        MULTIPLY,
        SCREEN,
        OVERLAY,

    }

    class Animation {
        onComplete: Phaser.Signal;
        reverse(): Animation;
        // More of course ...
    }


    class Signal {
        active: boolean;
        // More of course ...
    }

    class Game {
        constructor(width?: number | string, height?: number | string, renderer?: number, parent?: any, state?: any, transparent?: boolean, antialias?: boolean, physicsConfig?: any);
        context: CanvasRenderingContext2D;
        // More of course ...
    }

    class Physics {

        constructor(game: Phaser.Game, config?: any);

        static ARCADE: number;
        static P2JS: number;
        static NINJA: number;
        static BOX2D: number;
        static CHIPMUNK: number;
        static MATTERJS: number;

        arcade: Phaser.Physics.Arcade;
        config: any;
        game: Phaser.Game;
        ninja: Phaser.Physics.Ninja;
        p2: Phaser.Physics.P2;
        box2d: any; // Id like to override this, if you have any good idea I take it :p

    }

    module Physics {

        class Arcade {

        }

        class Ninja {

        }

        class P2 {

        }


        module P2 {

            class Body {

                static DYNAMIC: number;
                static STATIC: number;
                static KINEMATIC: number;
            }
        }
    }
}


// I want to add this class to the Physics module...
class MyAwesomeWork {
    constructor(hello: string) {
        console.log(hello);
    }
}

declare module Phaser {
    module Physics {
        class Box2D {

        }
        module Box2D {
            // ... But this fails :(
            class Body {

            }
        }
    }
}

Phaser.Physics.Box2D = MyAwesomeWork;
```

Comment: "I found this issue that explain how to add a new definition" are you missing a link?

Comment: yes, sorry I add it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution

```
import 'phaser-ce';

declare global {
    module Phaser {
        module Physics {
            class Box2D {
                prop: number;
                // Constructor declaration matters
                constructor(param: WhateverType);
            }
        }
    }
}

Phaser.Physics.Box2D = class {
    public prop = 42;
    constructor(private param: WhateverType) {}
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not supposed to directly modify or extend external packages, because if the module is updated, then the code you added would be rewritten. Unfortunately, it is impossible to directly modify a library.

The way most developers get around this is by writing their own augmentations and wrappers in their source code. That way, this custom class you have won't be rewritten by new `npm install`s.

This is not unique to TypeScript, that's how it works for JavaScript too. The only reason you can augment types by yourself is because not all packages are typed, and for the sake of static typing, TS assumes you know better. Additionally, those types are not in the compiled code, so modifying them has no effect on the end product. However, for the actual executable code, TS and JS assumes that library author is right, forcing you to put your own changes in your own codebase.

Comment: It's always possible to write "My.Lib.Namespace.Foo = function() { }" in JS. In my case I justify it because the lib actually use "Phaser.Physics.Box2D" while it's not defined (and need to be so the lib can work properly with Box2D). So I guess you was speaking about something totally different than my problem.

Comment: In that case, you'll probably have to augment the library in JavaScript, and modify the typings in your custom header file (d.ts). TS tends to complain if you try to modify lib code

Comment: That's indeed my last option. :(